# Клик по соседнему элементу

Tags: javascript, jquery

у меня есть некоторая проблема с кликом по соседней ссылке, подскажите как решить это. Вот мой скрипт

```
// Submit Button
$('.submit_button').click( function () {
    let thisButton = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        let nextObject = thisButton.next();
        nextObject.click();
        console.log(nextObject);
    }, 500);
});
```

В случае если разметка выглядит так

```
<button type="button"></button>
<button type="submit"></button>
```

Оно работает
Но если так

```
<button type="button"></button>
<a href="#" class="d-none"></a>
```

Оно не работает

Comment: А где у Вас в разметке вообще элемент с классом .submit_button, по которому совершается клик?

Comment: Это я к примеру разметку написал, естественно вид такой
<button type="button" class="submit_button"></button>
<a href="#" class="d-none"></a>

Comment: Ну, сама функция click() не очень надёжная, многие современные браузеры её блокируют (потому что небезопасно). Возможно, в этом проблема

Comment: Хорошо, а какие варианты есть по переходу по ссылке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае может быть несколько подходов. 
Если Вы знаете индекс (к примеру, они идут у Вас соответствующе), то можно использовать `links`.

```js
    $('.submit_button').click( function () {
        let thisButton = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            let nextObject = thisButton.next();
            nextObject.click();
            document.links[0].click();
        }, 500);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="submit_button"></button>
<a href="#123" class="d-none">123</a>
```

Если они Вам не известны, то можно воспользоваться следующим:

```js
    $('.submit_button').click( function () {
        let thisButton = $(this);
        setTimeout(function() {
            let nextObject = thisButton.next();
            nextObject.click();
            var href = nextObject. attr("href");
            location.href = href;
        }, 500);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="submit_button"></button>
<a href="#123" class="d-none">123</a>
```

Comment: Да это работает, но в моем случае я бы смог прописать target _blank а сейчас получается нужно как-то через js открывать новую вкладку, в любом случае вам спасибо огромное за ответ.